# New badge idea: Grinder

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

User has a reputation above a certain amount with less than a certain number badges. Intended for users who get lots of points a little at a time through many questions/answers. Would help users who get discouraged because they even though they are contributing they aren't earning many badges.

Comment: Sounds like you want something similar to Tenacious/Unsung Hero?

Answer (score 15):

I don't think this would be a good idea. I generally don't like the idea of badges that just reward gaining reputation, because reputation and the associated privileges are *already* the rewards for doing that.

The other part of your suggested criteria, fewer than a certain number of badges, is not good both because it encourages users *not* to get badges (which themselves generally promote good behavior), and because it makes the badge impossible to earn for a significant population of the site. This currently only applies to the precognitive and beta badges.